# Indentation marker/vertical lines for Python in pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, aptana, pydev

Is there a setting in Pydev source editor (Aptana studio for Eclipse) where I can see what indentation level a particular line in a Python file has? Something like a vertical line or a marker on the top/bottom window edges (as seen in image processing tools).

When having source code with a couple of indentation levels is can be quite hard to see what level it has:

```
def foo():
  while True:
    #stuff
    #stuff
    if "foo" == "bar":
      #stuff
      #stuff
      while False:
        #stuff
        #stuff
        #stuff
        #stuff
        if "baz" == "baz":
          #stuff
          #stuff
        else:
          #stuff
          #stuff
        #stuff
    #stuff ------> would be nice to have some visible cue that this is on level with the 'if'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doesn't look like it is available out of the box, however it is possible to add with plugins, for example:

- http://sschaef.github.io/IndentGuide/
- http://editbox.sourceforge.net/

or you can configure to show whitespaces, however, it doesn't give you vertical indent guide, unless you willing to count dots: Preferences -> General -> Text Editors -> Show whitespace characters

Comment: cool plugin, for some reason I had to use the link http://sschaef.github.io/IndentGuide/update/ in order to download it in eclipse